# How to edit margin when printing to PDF file?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, print-to-pdf, acrobat-pro-dc

I want to asymmetrically increase margins of a PDF file. I know that I can print it with a larger page size, then crop the new one as how I want, but is there a way to do that before printing?

[image]

Comment: Different PDF Printers have different options. Given that each PDF printer behaves differently and I don't have experience with Adobe PDF, I can't help you with this. Also, given that you have another question which is far more suitable for what you want to achieve than this while the objective is in essence the same, I think you should remove this question and focus on the other one.

Comment: Yes, that one is closer to what I want. But since these are still two different questions, shouldn't it be opened here?

Comment: They are two questions that ultimately do the same thing, which means, if the other question is answered, you are likely not going to care for this question anymore. That means, this question is going to be a waste for SuperUser, especially if someone bothers to answer it and your reply is: well thanks, already sorted it differently. (or not respond at all) But if you really need both answered, then yes, it's valid to keep this here.

Comment: @LPChip I agree that if the other question is answered, I don't need this one. But what if someone else actually needs it? Stack Exchange does encourage asking questions interesting for other people, not just me